# Does typescript automatically bundle all exports as default?

Tags: mongodb, typescript

`import * as mongodbModule from 'mongodb';`

The above code is the standard es6 way to import mongodb in nodejs, doing it like so `import mongodbModule from 'mongodb'` is supposed to throw an error because the mongodb module has no default export; but it still works. I discovered that the mongodb module is a typescript file hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

Whether or not you can write `import mongodbModule from 'mongodb'` without getting an error depends on your configuration in `.tsconfig`.  In order to enable this, you use the setting `--allowSyntheticDefaultImports`.  As explained in [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowSyntheticDefaultImports), it's not really that typescript creates the bundle, it's more that typescript assumes that the bundle exists and allows you to import it, while babel handles the actual creation of it.

> This flag does not affect the JavaScript emitted by TypeScript, it only for the type checking. This option brings the behavior of TypeScript in-line with Babel, where extra code is emitted to make using a default export of a module more ergonomic. ... For convenience, transpilers like Babel will automatically create a default if one isn’t created.